# Visual Studio 2013; just my code - mycode.json

Tags: debugging

I'm trying to figure out the mycode.json file that can be used in combination with the "just my code" service of Visual Studio 2013. However it's not making sense to me
For those who know not what "just my code" is: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/11/25/just-my-code-for-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

This is my scenario
I have a  project that is using jquery libraries and my own custom js file, called myconsents.js
I want to be able to debug this only, but for some reason the debugger keeps jumping into the jquery libraries. 
This is how my mycode.json file looks like

```
{
    "Eval" : "MyCode",
    "Function" : "Library",
    "ScriptBlock" : "Unrelated",
    "MyCode" : [
    "myconsents.js"
    ],
    "Libraries" : [
        "*.min.js", "jquery.*.js", "jquery-*.js"

    ],
    "Unrelated" : [
    ]
}
```

I hope you can provide a solution
Thanks

Comment: Did you ensure that the Just My Code option was enabled under Tools > Options > Debugging?

Comment: Yest I have checked that already

Answer (score 0):

I found that Visual Studio was ignoring my `mycode.json` file because I had put a JavaScript-style comment at the beginning:

```js
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx#BKMK_JavaScript_Just_My_Code
{
    "MyCode": [ ],
    "Libraries": [ "*-min.js" ],
    "Unrelated": [ ]
}
```

VS started working as expected after removing the comment.